# Not seeing all ListBoxItems in my custom ListBoxControl

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a custom ListBox control where I set the Source to a collection of 250 objects. When the control is displayed, my overrides for GetContainerForItemOverride() and PrepareContainerForItemOverride() are called for about 3 pages (where a page is the height of the ListBoxControl) worth of items. As I swipe upwards the items scroll up but once the last item of the 3 pages worth is scrolled up from the bottom, there are no more calls to my GetContainerForItemOverride() and PrepareContainerForItemOverride() overrides to get & display the rest of the items. Instead the items keep scrolling up by the amount that I swipe. It takes the same amount of swiping to bring the last item back into view from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ScrollIntoView method